# How to convert C# Linq to query in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I'm a junior developer and trying to convert the following **linq** statement to T-SQL:

```
var items = from u in DataContext.Users_SearchUsers(searchPara.UserFirstName,
                                                    searchPara.UserLastName,
                                                    searchPara.UserEmailAddress,
                                                    fetchOptions.page,
                                                    fetchOptions.rp,
                                                    fetchOptions.sortname,
                                                    fetchOptions.sortorder)
                                 .ToList()
            join a in DataContext.UserAccesses
                                 .Where(x => x.Access.AccessTypeId == 4).ToList() on u.UserID equals a.UserId into accessGroup
            select new {};
```

Can one please help me ? `into accessGroup` ---> (very important)

Comment: Why should it be manually translated to SQL? A package like entity framework does that under the hood?

Comment: The DataContext class already hints that a library like Entity Framework. The generated queries are logged in the console, you could use that as starting point

Comment: you can put a break point befor execute your link code and get the txt of query or set a sql server profiller for monitor the query come from code or applications and you can use third party application that can profile the query this app is ef profiller

Comment: Apart from the useful comments above, your code is too sketchy to make any serious effort. Where does `fetchOptions` come from? If `fetchOptions` is something local then how could that ever be translated into SQL?

Comment: `join`...`into` in LINQ has no direct SQL equivalent. It is a `GroupJoin`. However, you can use `GROUP BY` after a `LEFT JOIN` to create something similar in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand where your data is coming from. You are loading information from `Users_SearchUsers` on the one hand and `UserAccesses` on the other hand. The first query looks like

```
select <somecolumns>
from users
where <somefilters>;
```

(you need to use your actual columns and criteria, but `Users_SearchUsers` is not specified in the question at all). I have ignored paging here for the sake of simplicity

The second query looks like this:

```
select *
from user_accesses
where access_type_id = 4;
```

Let's join the two:

```
select <someoutercolumns>
from
(
select <someinnercolumns>
from users
where <somefilters>
) t1
join
(
select <someotherinnercolumns>
from user_accesses
where access_type_id = 4
) t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user_id;
```

These queries are probably not the exact solutions you need, but you want the answers to improve, then improve your question.

The requirement makes sense if the LINQ query is very slow. In that case you will need to refactor it in the following manner:

```
select <somecolumns>
from users
join user_accesses
on users.user_id = user_accesses.user_id and user_accesses.access_type_id = 4
where <somefilters>;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
select *(you can put your columns instead *)
from Users
join UserAccesses
on Users.userid = UserAccesses.userid
where UserAccesses.typeid = 4;
```